# Wordpress duplicating when creating post programmatically

Tags: wordpress

When running the below function it seems to create duplicate copy for some reason, could someone suggest something that will stop this or another work around.

```
function createNewPost()
{
global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
'post_title' => 'My New Post',
'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
}
```

Not sure what the issue is as the code seems fine, tested on standard template but still the same issue.

Comment: How do you run it?  By refreshing the page?  If so, are you sure you aren't refreshing more than once?

Comment: At first I ran it through a snippet within my wp site, then ran as standard .php file on the server, but same issue.